# PowerShell Backup copies Files outside of Backup-Zip

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, 7zip

I am working on a Backup tool with PowerShell and I have a problem where a Zip-File with the Backup is created but the files are also copied outside of the Zip-File so at the end of the day I have them 2 times. I'll attach the code and a picture of the Backup. Would be nice if someone could tell me why the other files are being copied.

btw. I'm using robocopy and 7-Zip.

[image: Backup in Folder]

```
if ($backupType -eq "v") {    
# Ask user for password
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Geben Sie ein Passwort zum Verschlüsseln des Backups ein"

# Create a 7-Zip Archive
$arguments = "a -tzip `"$destinationPath\backup.zip`" `"$sourcePath\*`" -p$password"
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait

# Copy Files with Robocopy, excluding .zip files
robocopy $sourcePath $destinationPath /E /XF *.zip

# Generate a Logfile
robocopy $destinationPath $logPath /L /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /NC /NFL /NDL /NP /BYTES /XJ /R:0 /W:0 > $logPath
}
```

Comment: Can you share what "I have a problem where a Zip-File with the Backup is created but the files are also copied outside of the Zip-File" has to do with the `aaa.txt` and `bbb.txt` ?  How are you starting your script ?

Comment: "Would be nice if someone could tell me why the other files are being copied." ROBOCOPY will copy files.... your question is unclear!

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses Zip for *compressed folders* and integrates them so that they behave like regular folders. I believe that this only happens for zip files with a single folder in the root, so it is not a simple matter of excluding all zip files, because some may not be compressed folders.

You would perhaps somehow need to skip *folders* that have a name matching *.zip, but allow *files* *.zip. Not familiar enough with either robocopy or power shell to advise.

However it seems to me perhaps you don't need robocopy and certainly not 7-Zip.  Windows has zip support built in via its compressed folders feature. This can be used in Power shell using [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Windows zip is not capable of adding a password..

Comment: @Luuk Can you add a password to an existing zip file?  Perhaps you can use 7-Zip to do that to a compressed folder (which is just a regular zip file).  Or use powershell's support for encryption? `(Get-Item –Path xxxx.zip).Encrypt()`?  Other than that your question was about why it happens, the suggested solution was a bonus ;-).  In that sense, this answers the question since you did not ask for a solution.  Understanding the cause should enable you to arrive at a solution.

Comment: My comment was also just a suggestion. Adding a password to an, already existing, compressed file it something which (IMHO) is also not supported by 7-zip. And powershell `encrypt()` does do something else than adding a password to a compressed (.zip or .7z) file.

Comment: @Luuk  .  Understood.  Some discussion on that https://superuser.com/questions/214823/add-password-to-existing-zip-file-with-7zip and perhaps https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/password-protect-a-zip-file-on-windows-10-with-images.  But my favourite simplest solution: https://packages.msys2.org/package/zip includes zipcloak for Windows